# how to keep the dockMenu open when clicking items in cocoa app

Tags: swift, cocoa

i have items in my dock menu that needs the dock menu to stay open
when the items are clicked

im refering to when u right click on an app and you get the dock menu

automaticly, it closes it

anyway to override this?

Comment: What are you doing that you need a menu to stay open?

Comment: changing multiple preferences so the user doesnt have to re open the menu each time

Comment: Usually one would use a preferences window or dialog.  Menus aren't really designed for that.

Comment: yes, but my app is differant it doesnt have a window an the whole thing is controled via that right click menu, its realy slick

Comment: Your app doesn't need to have a window, just put up a panel or an alert when the a preferences menu item is clicked - several NSStatusItem apps also do this.

Comment: but would u know of a way to prevent dockmenu from closing when items are clicked?

Comment: No.  As I mentioned earlier, menus aren't designed to work that way.

Comment: thx for your answer red menace

Comment: This sounds more like the sort of thing I would expect on the Menu Bar, with no Dock - you would still need a panel for setting multiple preferences etc. See Caffeine for example - http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/.

Comment: @Giles i understand what you are saying but i realy want to keep the dockmenu open when items are clicked on, anything i could duck tape in to make this work?

Comment: Maybe the actions that don't dismiss the menu could make a copy of the menu and maintain it in some way.